# InputStream doesn't run

Tags: android, inputstream

I'm doing a small android project, which the first feature is to connect to my server and execute a php parser for take some articles. My on create invoke this method:

```
private String jsonTaker() throws IOException, JSONException {  
    //call EventsTaker class -> take the 'articles'
    JsonReader jsr = new JsonReader();

    JSONObject json =     jsr.readJsonFromUrl("http://jem88.net/timeSpaceParser.php");
    System.out.println(json.toString());
    System.out.println(json.get("id"));

    return json.toString();
}
```

this is the `readJsonFromUrl()` and `readAll()` method:

```
public JSONObject readJsonFromUrl(String url) throws IOException, JSONException {
    InputStream is = new URL (url).openStream();
    //sia maledetto il creatore di java e tutta la sua genia diojavosogeloso
    InputStreamReader isr = new InputStreamReader(is, Charset.forName("UTF-8"));
    BufferedReader rd = new BufferedReader(isr);
    String jsonText = readAll(rd);
    JSONObject json = new JSONObject(jsonText);
    Log.d("readJsonFromUrl", "String to json transformed!");
    is.close();
    return json;        
}

private static String readAll(Reader rd) throws IOException {
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    int cp;
    while ((cp = rd.read()) != -1) {
        sb.append((char) cp);
    }
    return sb.toString();
}
```

The error appears when on debug mode, the executions arrive to the first line of `readJsonFromUrl()` method, where I try to open the stream. Here the application crashes with 'Source not found' error. I've tried googling about this, but no one of the suggestion given was good for me! So, any suggestion would be great!

EDIT -> I've edited the exception's manage, and now I catch a FATAL Exception. Here is the logcat:

```
06-04 23:46:56.411: D/AndroidRuntime(22456): Shutting down VM
06-04 23:46:56.411: W/dalvikvm(22456): threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x40e312a0)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456): java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.jem88.timespace/com.jem88.timespace.MainActivity}: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2110)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2135)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.access$700(ActivityThread.java:140)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1237)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:4921)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:511)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1027)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:794)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456): Caused by: android.os.NetworkOnMainThreadException
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.os.StrictMode$AndroidBlockGuardPolicy.onNetwork(StrictMode.java:1118)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at java.net.InetAddress.lookupHostByName(InetAddress.java:385)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByNameImpl(InetAddress.java:236)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at java.net.InetAddress.getAllByName(InetAddress.java:214)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:70)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.<init>(HttpConnection.java:50)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection$Address.connect(HttpConnection.java:340)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnectionPool.get(HttpConnectionPool.java:87)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpConnection.connect(HttpConnection.java:128)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.openSocketConnection(HttpEngine.java:315)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.connect(HttpEngine.java:310)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendSocketRequest(HttpEngine.java:289)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpEngine.sendRequest(HttpEngine.java:239)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getResponse(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:273)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at libcore.net.http.HttpURLConnectionImpl.getInputStream(HttpURLConnectionImpl.java:168)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at java.net.URL.openStream(URL.java:462)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at com.jem88.timespace.JsonReader.readJsonFromUrl(JsonReader.java:44)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at com.jem88.timespace.MainActivity.jsonTaker(MainActivity.java:46)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at com.jem88.timespace.MainActivity.onCreate(MainActivity.java:23)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5206)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1094)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2074)
06-04 23:46:56.436: E/AndroidRuntime(22456):    ... 11 more
```

Comment: Did you add internet permission?

Comment: Could you add the logcat output to your question?

Comment: yes NickF, i do! Now i add the log output!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just put in it in separated thread than main thread , I tested your code by myself

```
    Thread tr=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            try {
            Log.v("Alefon", jsonTaker());   
            } catch (IOException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("Alefon", "errr"+e.getMessage());
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                Log.e("Alefon", "errr "+e.getMessage());
            }
        }
    });

    tr.start();
```

It would be better by practices to use AsyncTask see : [link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html)

Comment: I've just try to put it into another class, an it work! Now i've implement my code like you, and works this way too!! Thanx all you for help!